# Position fixed and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

this is my css. It is working fine in firefox but not working in IE.

```
#Createinner {
    position: fixed; 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 280px; 
    margin-left: -200px; 
    margin-top: -140px; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    background-color: #ccc; 
}
```

How to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Today there was a post on Smashing Magazine about negative margins: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/ maybe it helps

Answer (score 41):

Simply add DocType Tag on top of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: But HOW does it help? I mean, what's the logic behind it working?

Comment: This does not solve the problem in cases of injected code, or otherwise unmanageable doctypes, naturally, but maybe the best canonical answer.  

To answer above comment - this clearly stated doc type tag lets the browser know it should be using a more standards compliant browser mode and not a quirksmode.

Comment: Note the `XHTML` - I had just `HTML` and simply adding the X made the difference

Answer (score 34):

What sorted my problem with IE was the code in:

http://annevankesteren.nl/test/examples/ie/position-fixed.html

basically added:

```
 h1{
  position:fixed;
  _position:absolute;
  top:0;
  _top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful reference. It works (as tested in IE7 & IE8)

Comment: Thank you it worked perfect for me! I have another question: In my code, there are 2 div the first is the menu, and the second one is the title (that changes on every page).  How can I set both divs as fixed? and I want the second div start inmediatly after the first div.

Comment: Thanks! Also, it works in IE6 too... Yes I tested on IE6 Win XP.

Comment: This doesn't works in IE9+. To get it working there - go http://stackoverflow.com/a/29170804/729768

Answer (score 2):

for fixed position in IE 8
**DOCTYPE** is very very important.

one of:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

And its very very important that

### those be in first line.

css:

```
#footer
  {position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; }
```

html:

```
<div id="footer" >
       Fixed Div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't support position fixed.

If you really need this to work in IE6, use conditional comments to serve an IE only CSS file and fake `position:fixed` with CSS expressions.

(edited to correct IE version info.)

Comment: The answer strongly implies that IE7 does not support position: fixed. It does.

Comment: Ok, that's worth correcting, but the solution is still valid.

Comment: Possibly. There are other factors which can influence it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a jQuery plugin to get position:fixed working in IE 6+. It *doesn't* jitter on scroll, it looks at capability (not user-agent), works in Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8.

If you use strict mode in IE7+ position:fixed will be honoured, but by default IE7+ operates in Quirks Mode. This plugin checks for browser capability, and if it doesn't honour position:fixed, then it implements the jQuery fix.

http://code.google.com/p/fixedposition/

Something like this may work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#Createinner").fixedPosition({
      debug: true,
      fixedTo: "bottom"
   });
});
```

You may need to make some minor CSS adjustments to get it working for your code. I'm working on "offset" values as options as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

1. Versions of IE pre 8 do not support position fixed properly.
2. What is the problem with the CSS e.g. why is it not working, what do you see on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

http://ieproblems.blogspot.com/ use this one it will solve your problem

```
#mainDiv{
overflow:auto;
}

#subDiv{
position:relative;
top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop+'px');
left:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop+'px');
}

<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<div id="mainDiv">
<div id="subDiv">
This Text is Fixed
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

<del>You have tagged this as HTML but `` is not an HTML element. Internet Explorer will not let you style elements that it does not recognise.

 - Use only [HTML elements][1] in HTML documents</del>



You have updated your question so that it appears you are using an id selector not a type selector. This renders my original comment irrelevant.

IE 6 does not support `position: fixed`

- Use [workarounds](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=FixedLayouts) if you need to support IE6

Other versions of IE don't support `position: fixed` in quirks mode

- Use a [standards mode triggering Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) (generally HTML 4.01 Strict is the right choice)

Comment: He's not using CreateInner as a HTML element

Comment: He's using Createinner is the id of an element. Nothing wrong with that.