# IE7 modal lightbox overlay disappears when scrolling

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I was hoping to get some help with a bug on a development site I'm stuck on. I'm trying to do a lightbox at the bottom of this page: http://learningseat.wpdemo.com.au/discover/#links. Click on one of the four circular buttons to trigger the lightbox.

I'm having issues with the #fade overlay that I append to the bottom of the page when one of the buttons is clicked. When I scroll up on the page the overlay doesn't cover the other elements higher up the page in IE7.

Has anyone got any pointers for me? I have been using Internet Explorer 9 with IE7 rendering on for testing and I've added a 4px solid red border around the #fade div for testing and I've also got Firebug Lite on the page to help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this topic: [Position fixed and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193255/position-fixed-and-internet-explorer)

Possibilities:

- Add a strict doctype. But since you're using HTML5, I suspect that can't be done.
- Use Riga's work-around:

`

```
#fade {
  position:fixed;
  _position:absolute;
  top:0;
  _top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop));
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .2;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

`