# CSS fixed header in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The following code works fine but when it comes to Ie 7 and 8 it does not anymore.
Basically when I scroll the header should stay fixed and the content scroll underneath. In IE the header is all over the place.

```
.header{
position: fixed;
background-color:#000;
top: 0;
height: 46px;
width: 940px;
margin-left: 50%;
padding-top: 4px;
left: -470px;
}
```

is there a solution with just CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193255/position-fixed-and-internet-explorer

Comment: yes I know i do accept when the answer helps, in this case I found the solution in the link suggested by F4r-20 :)