# CSS Position Fixed Not Working in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I have an image gallery, with captions across the bottom (upper image). The captions use `position:fixed; bottom:0;`, and works in every browser but IE, even the latest version (11.096…). The caption is fixed to the top of the screen, instead of the bottom (lower image).

[image: How it should look]
[image: How it looks in IE]

I tried some of the suggestions I found while researching this on my own:

- Verified the correct doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">`
- Added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`
- Added expressions to my CSS:
  `position:fixed;
  _position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  _top:expression(document.body.scrollTop+document.body.clientHeight-this.clientHeight);`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Pardon my thickness if there's an obvious purpose I'm missing here, but aren't you forcing the browser into IE7 compatibility mode wit that `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag? Would replacing `IE=EmulateIE7` with `IE=edge` not make it behave as expected?

Comment: I thought so, too. But I read that in a post, and tried it, and i just wanted to indicate that before someone else suggested it.

Comment: Ah, ok. It looks like you've figured out a workaround based on the suggestion below. Happy IE debugging!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Try using `position: expression(fixed);`
2. Try using `position: relative;` on the parent element and `position: absolute;` on your caption. This is cross-browser.

Comment: Number 2 is not an option, in this case. The enclosing div needs to be absolute for the slider to work.

Comment: Did you try it? Positioning should work for an absolute element inside another absolute element.

Comment: It turns out that the problem was another CSS file, the one that came with the WP plugin that creates the slideshow. For some reason my custom CSS was not overriding it in IE. In every other browser, it worked as expected, but IE kept applying it.

Weird.

I did wind up changing it to absolute, though. It achieved the same effect, and is guaranteed to work. Thanks!